# South migration for dummy fields

Tags: python, django, django-south

We have a dummy Python module (`fields.py`) with custom Django fields which loads real implementations based on the database configured:

```
if settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'].find('postgresql') != -1:
  from fields_postgresql import *
else:
  from fields_dummy import *
```

The reason for this is that we are using PostgreSQL ip4r extension which allows nice (and fast) work with fields containing IP values. But we also have dummy implementations (in Python code) for other databases, so that development can be done also in SQLite. So if you are using PostgreSQL those fields are backed up with fields using ip4r indexes and if you are using some other database system those fields are regular fields.

The problem is how to use South migrations on such fields. The problem is that `add_introspection_rules` discovers `fields_postgresql` and `fields_dummy` so this leaks to migrations. This is the problem later on if you want to apply a migration made with SQLite on an installation with PostgreSQL.

How it would be possible to convince South that this is all just `fields` module and it does not matter which concrete implementation migrations are run with.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If yes, please accept it. If not, it would be great to hear some criticism/see a better solution.

Comment: No, sorry. It didn't work. It is not enough just to ignore the field, the field has to be in the migration. Just South should see both implementations as equal.

Comment: OK, did you try to customise `add_introspection_rules` loading based on what database is currently in use?

Comment: I didn't find a way to infulence the name of the module with ``add_introspection_rules``.

Comment: I'll checkout South code in a few days. It looks like you will need to employ a custom South-based script to create migrations. Overall, your approach for mixing SQLite and Postgre in one project doesn't seem like a good idea. (But that's just my opinion.)

Comment: Yes, I agree it is not a good idea. I will probably drop support for SQLite. But it is handy for develpoment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drop support for SQLite**.

You are right, if you aren't running your development environment on a mobile phone, maintaining your very own South-based migration script just in a sake of not installing Postgre probably isn't worth the hassle.

Postgre installation versus maintaining custom migration code is a one-time action versus continuous and potentially time-consuming procedure (since you will potentially have to modify your custom migration code in order to be in sync with newer South releases).

Comment: That's true. But I hope for my Django application to be used also by others. And having an easy way to test drive my application is an important step towards adopting it. And do not requiring PostgreSQL is important for that. So my application is not used only internally and just by our developers, but we hope it will be used widely.

Comment: @Mitar, In the next days I'll try to figure out how this problem can be solved without dropping support of other databases.

Comment: @Mitar, how about the fact that most of external developers probably wont need to migrate your models? Does the core functionality require this field to be used in the users models?

Comment: Yes, field is required. It is true that migrations are probably not necessary, but once you have them in place it would be silly to turn them off for SQLite. ;-) But yes, it is another option.